# Google Script: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'namedValues' of 'e' as it is undefined. _onFormSubmit

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, typeerror

AnyOne Pls Check what and where went wrong. Checked for execution log which prevented the properties and object output returned with the error.
Execution Started and failed
"Triggered the _onSubmit Form(e) for the namedValues, but return error for undefined property @ Code.gs:18.

`

```
/**
 * @params (object)e
 * @params (SpreadSheetApp.Range) e.range
 * @params (object) e.namedvalues
 */

function _onFormSubmit(e) {
  if (e) throw new Error ("Auto Triggered only thru Form submit!  Manual Records prevented")
  //  console.log(e)

  const {namedValues, range} = e
  const sheet = range.getSheet()
//  const range(e)
  const formUrl = sheet.getFormUrl()
  // if (!formUrl) return                   // Dim (!formUrl) as it is auto submit form
  if(formUrl.includes.CONFIG.FORM_ID.CLOCK_IN) {
      handleClockIn_(e)
  } else if (formUrl.includes.CONFIG.FORM_ID.CLOCK_OUT) {       // Use multiple 'elseif' with this code for 2 or more
      handleClockOut_(e)
  }
}
```

`

Various Isses resolution attempt, but no adequate method

Comment: The error message is clear, namedValues was not defined in the event object. Try consol.log the event object to see what does it contains when the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
function onMyForm(e) {
  const {namedValues,values} = e;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(namedValues));
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values));
}
```